# After updating from moment version 2.24.0 to 2.29.4 moment related jest test case failed

Tags: ts-jest

Below mentioned jest test case worked fine until moment got updated from 2.24.0 to 2.29.4.
What could be the reason for this?

Failing Jest test case:

```
test("Verify dates are validated properly", () => {
    expect((moment("048710", moment.ISO_8601, true)).isValid()).toBeFalse();
    expect((moment("22390", moment.ISO_8601, true)).isValid()).toBeFalse();
    expect((moment("2020-01-01T00:00:00-00:00", moment.ISO_8601, true)).isValid()).toBeTrue();
    expect((moment("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z", moment.ISO_8601, true)).isValid()).toBeTrue();
});
```

Error message:
[image]

Comment: How did you enumerate all breaking changes for 2.24.0 => 2.29.4 upgrade?

Comment: @rajkumar - there was only one test where moment was used and it failed after moment upgrade.
I solved this issue by reverting the moment upgrade changes.